# class "org.slf4j.MavenSlf4jFriend"'s signer information does not match signer information of other classes in the same package

Tags: eclipse-photon

I have installed eclipse photon last week and maven build on my project was working fine until it is not updated with the latest. After taken updates, getting below error.

[ERROR] Error executing Maven. 
[ERROR] class "org.slf4j.MavenSlf4jFriend"'s signer information does not match signer information of other classes in the same package

Please share if any finding for the same.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I use the following workaround.

Install a new maven installation and do not use the embedded version.

I download the version from https://archive.apache.org/dist/maven/maven-3/3.5.3/binaries/.

Answer (score 1):

@Shukant
This bug only occurs in Photon M7 and was solved in Photon RC1 which will be available this week.

Answer (score 1):

It's now fixed, just update your Eclipse through Menu -> Help -> Check for Updates. :D

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in m2e's build, the jars of the Embedded Maven runtime were digitally signed with Eclipse's certificate, messing things up. See [Bug 534933](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=534933) for more details.

Anyways, a fix has been deployed for Photon RC1 and is available at http://download.eclipse.org/technology/m2e/milestones/1.9/